# How do I add an inherited control to a datatemplate in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I need to an extra dependancy property to a control, so I'm overriding it. I.E.:

```
namespace Custom_TextBlock_Sample
{
  public class CustomLabel: Label
  {

  }
}
```

But I seem to be unable to add it to a DataTemplate. The following code will fail to build:

```
 ... xmlns:Custom_TextBlock_Sample="clr-namespace:Custom_TextBlock_Sample" ...

   <DataTemplate x:Key="Test">
      <Grid>
        <Custom_TextBlock_Sample:CustomLabel></Custom_TextBlock_Sample:CustomLabel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

However inserting my overriden control anywhere else, (say not in the datatemplate) .. and compilation works no problem.

The following works: (My control is not nested in a date template).

```
  <Grid>
      <Custom_TextBlock_Sample:CustomLabel></Custom_TextBlock_Sample:CustomLabel>
  </Grid>
```

Also using a regular label in the Datatemplate also works:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Test">
  <Grid>
    <Label/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be ? Can I simply not add overridden controls to datatemplates in such a manor ? Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2007?

Note that since my intended changed to the control will be small, I simply want to override "Label" instead of wrapping it in a UserControl.

Thanks

Comment: This works fine for me and nothing looks wrong with the code you put here. What's the compile error you're getting? One possible problem might be if you're inheriting from the wrong Label class. Check the using statements in your CustomLabel file (ex. the Label in System.Reflection.Emit that is sealed and so wouldn't compile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. This seems to be a namespace bug with Visual Studio. The problem fixed itself, when I started a new project from scratch, this time with no spaces in the project name and no "_" in namespaces names.